# attribute doesn't add in stdClass object

Tags: php

I am developing a web application in laravel 5.3. The problem i am getting is that attributes doesn't add up in stdClass object, however you can see my code where i am explicitly setting/adding a new attributes in a object.

**problematic code**

```
1-  $sender = Sender::where('id', $this->senderId)->first();
2-  if ($sender != null) {
3-       var_dump($sender->bundle);
4-       $sender->bundle->latitude = $this->lat;
5-       $sender->bundle->longitude = $this->long;
6-       $sender->bundle->location = $response->formattedAddress();
7-       var_dump($sender->bundle);
8-       $sender->save();
9-       error_log('resolved');
10- } else {
11-      error_log('no sender');
12- }
```

In above code you can clearly see that i am setting some new properties for `bundle` object.

```
$sender->bundle->latitude = $this->lat;
$sender->bundle->longitude = $this->long;
$sender->bundle->location = $response->formattedAddress();
```

but in output you can clearly see that it doesn't get add up. The code basically runs in laravel queue. In above code `$sender` is laravel eloquent model and the attribute bundle is being `json_decode` via laravel mutators.

**mutator code**

```
public function setBundleAttribute($value) {
    $this->attributes['bundle'] = json_encode($value);
}

public function getBundleAttribute($value) {
    return json_decode($value);
}
```

**output of above problematic code**

```
object(stdClass)#686 (3) { #output of line 3
  ["city"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["province"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["country"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
object(stdClass)#686 (3) { #output of line 7
  ["city"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["province"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["country"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
[2017-07-25 16:11:03] Processed: App\Jobs\LocationResolverQueue
resolved
```

**Problem Solved**

laravel **Accessors & Mutators** cause the problem.
Accessor and Mutator get called whenever we get or set property respectively, in my case the mutator was calling whenever i try to access `$sender->bundle->property` however accessor didn't get called because i was setting a `$sender->bundle->property` rather than `$sender->bundle`
i solved problem like

```
$sender = Sender::where('id', $this->senderId)->first();
if ($sender != null) {
    $temp = $sender->bundle;
    $temp->latitude = $this->lat;
    $temp->longitude = $this->long;
    $temp->location = $response->formattedAddress();
    $sender->bundle = $temp;
    $sender->save();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to assign the full object to `bundle`?

Comment: Gino Pane you can see in the output that says `$sender->bundle` is `object(stdClass)#686`

Comment: Nope, I mean, to set the full object to bundle, like that: `$sender->bundle = $updatedBundle`.

Comment: you can see that in **mutator code**
`public function setBundleAttribute($value) {
   $this->attributes['bundle'] = json_encode($value);
}`

Comment: It is not the same. Just try.

Comment: @GinoPane yes may be you are right, as i already stated that i am using laravel model and don't know how laravel's mutator sets things up for me. So may be laravel model causing that all..

Comment: It can be quickly checked